# Proper configuration to mix Collations in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I’m a little confused by the collations. Not sure if the DB would traduce a column collation to the table collation on a `SELECT`, or is just a *ruleset* for when comparing. 
So what to put as `CHARSET` and `COLLATE`? (10.4.11-MariaDB)

Here are some examples of what I have:
Case #1: The `utf8_bin` column I just `SELECT` it, not compare it, but the `ascii` I do `WHERE bot=?`

```
CREATE TABLE `bots_trace` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `bot` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET ascii COLLATE ascii_bin NOT NULL,
  `info` varchar(2000) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `seen` enum('yes','no') CHARACTER SET ascii COLLATE ascii_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT 'no'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

I almost never ask the DB to do an `utf8mb4_bin` comparison or similar, just `SELECT`.
So what collations I should use in those cases, what to use as `DEFAULT` and as `COLLATE`

Case #2: The only time I ask the DB to do something with an uft8mb4 is to check the mail.

```
 CREATE TABLE `changed_email` (
      `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
      `old_mail` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL,
      `ctime` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
      `ip` varchar(94) CHARACTER SET ascii COLLATE ascii_bin NOT NULL
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin;

SELECT id FROM changed_email WHERE old_mail = ? LIMIT 1
```

What to do in this case? Because the only comparison I do is a `utf8mb4_bin` I'm assuming that would be the correct `CHARSET` & `COLLATE`.

Also, I use PHP and I set `mysqli_set_charset($link, 'utf8mb4')`, which I needed to retrieve the data correctly, if I change some table `COLLATION` to `ascii`, could I have trouble retrieving `utf8mb4` data columns?

Comment: `_bin` basically assumes that when you search for `Cat` you do not want to find `cat` or `CAT`; and when you sort results you don't want to use dictionary order. Is that really you intention?

Comment: @Álvaro That I know, _bin is binary comparison which makes it case sensitive, yes it's my intent.
What I'm asking is, in the tables where I mix utf8 and ascii, for the scenarios and uses explained, what I should set as CHARSET and COLLATE. I believe Case #1 COLLATE would be ascii_bin, and 2# utf8mb4_bin.

Comment: It is not necessary to repeat tag information in the title of your post. The tagging system works extremely well here and doesn't need any help.

Answer (score 1):

`ascii` encoding is a subset of `utf8` which is a subset of `utf8mb4`.  But that is probably irrelevant.

`mysqli_set_charset()` announces the `CHARACTER SET` of the data in the *client*.

MySQL, during `INSERT` will convert the bytes from the encoding indicated by `mysqli_set_charset` to the encoding specified for the column in the table.  Similarly `SELECT` will convert the other direction.

If you are only dealing with ascii characters, then there is effectively no conversion, and no possibility of problems.  If, on the other hand, you have accented letters or Emoji, there will be problems.

The above talks about `CHARACTER SET`, which is the "encoding" of letters.  the `COLLATION` is a different matter; this term refers to the ordering, including case folding and accent stripping.  For example, should `'a' = 'A'` or not?  For `COLLATION` ascii_general_ci or utf8mb4...ci, those are "equal".  For any collation `...bin` they are "not equal", and one of them will consistently be sorted (think `ORDER BY`) before the other.

In some, but not all, situations, MySQL will allow mixing character sets or collections, and "do the right thing".  For example, storing a character in once `CHARACTER SET` into another, either it can be converted, or it will mess up.  `A` is available in perhaps all character sets, but, for example, an accented `A` is not available in Ascii.

In the case of `COLLATION`, when there is a conflict of collections, there may be a rule that says which collation to use, but often it gives up and complains about a "mix of collections".

Keep in mind that all of this comes from multiple places:

- The column definition
- The connection parameters (between client and MySQL server)
- The bytes in the *client*.

A common example is `latin1` accented letters cannot be *interpreted* as utf8 bytes, but they can be *converted* to utf8.  This raises its ugly head when connection specification disagrees with the bytes in the client.